# drawing the tangent to the curve knowing the point and gradient

Tags: math, d3.js

I writing a computer program to back up my knowledge of calculus.  You can see the web page [here](http://www.d3geometry.com/functions)

The next thing I want to do is display a tangent to the curve when the user hovers the mouse over the curve.

When that happens, I know exactly the coordinates of the mouse and I can get the derivative which in this case is 2x -2 so if the point is at (1, 1) then the gradient would be 0.

If I was drawing this with pen and paper then I would rearrange the equation into y2-y1 = m(x2 -x1).

I am not entirely sure how to do this with code though.

I tried getting the y intercept and x intercept but the tangent looked wrong:

```
function getYIntercept(vertex, slope) {
  return vertex.y - (slope * vertex.x);
}

const yIntercept = getYIntercept(point, gradient);
const xIntercept =  - yIntercept / (gradient);

g.append('line')
    .style('stroke', 'red')
    .attr('class', 'tangent')
    .attr('x1', xScale(point.x))
    .attr('y1', yScale(point.y))
    .attr('x2', xScale(xIntercept))
    .attr('y2', yScale(yIntercept));
};
```

How better can I plot this line with the information I have?

[image]

Comment: ``d f(x) / dx = 2*x - 2`` if I am not mistaken. Not ``2x``.

Comment: @BitTickler you are correct, I have updated the question but it was just a typo from me.  The code was working it out correctly

Comment: In the site http://www.d3geometry.com/functions it seems you have minified the whole code...can you give a fiddle where i can play around?

Comment: For (1,1) -> x = 1, m = 2 * 1 - 2 = 0, not 2 ;) (you might also want to correct that)

Comment: [This](http://jsfiddle.net/djatha/JmGC3/) might help.

Answer (score 1):

### Finding the Tangent

- Let us start with a function **f(x)**.
- Calculate **f '(x)** (the derivative) for future reference.
- Then the user indicates some point **(x1, y1)**.
- Using *f '(x)*, the slope at this point is **m = f '(x1)**.
- Utilizing the Point-Slope formula, the equation for tangent is  **y-y1 = m(x-x1)**
- Solve for **y**:

  - **y = m(x-x1)+y1**

---

### Finding the Intercepts

For the x and y intercepts [denoted here as *x0* and *y0* respectively], simply use the tangent equation. It may be useful to note that the intercepts are **(x0,0)** and **(0,y0)** so plugging in zero for the correct variable allows you to find a intercept.

- Find the y intercept, so **x=0**
- Thus **y = m(0-x1)+y1**
- Distributing the *m* leaves **y = -m*x1+y1**
- So **y0 = -m*x1+y1** and the y intercept is **( 0, -m*x1+y1 )**

This is all that is needed to graph the tangent. But in case you're are curious about the x intercept as well.

- Find the x intercept, so **y=0**
- Thus **0 = m(x-x1)+y1**
- Distributing the *m* leaves **0 = m*x - m*x1 + y1**
- Subtracting the *x1* and *y1* terms yields **m*x1-y1 = m*x**
- Now divide by *m* so that **[ m*x1-y1 ]/m = x**
- So **x0 = [ m*x1-y1 ]/m** and the x intercept is **( [ m*x1-y1 ]/m, 0 )**

---

### Specifics for this Case

Here are some issues:

- **(1, 1)** is not a point on the function **f(x) = x^2 - 2*x + 1**

  - To solve this, you could simply use only the x-value of the point the user hovers over
  - Alternatively, you could consider graphing the [slope field](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Slope_field)
- The x intercept and y intercept are two distinct points, not the x and y value of one point

Once these issues are resolved, you will be able to  properly graph the tangent of any function for which you know the first derivative!

Comment: Thank you for the answer. 

I disagree with your point that the calculation for the y intercept is y1 + m*x1, I think mine is correct